# LINUX: Herencia permisos grupos y usuarios

Tags: linux, permisos

estoy configurando un punto de montaje para varios usuarios y grupos pero no consigo dar la tecla.

Tengo un punto de montaje \home y dentro de este varias carpetas para distintas unidades. cada unidad tiene su usuario y grupo owner (chown).

Solo consigo poner bien los permisos con chmod de forma individual pero no consigo ver yo todos los ficheros con mi uusario personal sin usar el usuario root.

He estado buscando por internet pero todo lo que he visto es usar chown, chmod y los owners de las carpetas pero no hay manera.

¿que se me escapa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo bien el problema, pero me parecería que lo que buscas es aplicar los permisos recursivamente. Por ejemplo, si tienes la siguiente estructura:

```
/home/
  |- user1-dir/
     |- dir1/
     |- dir2/
  |- user2-dir/
     |- dir3/
     |- dir4/
```

y quieres que todos los archivos y directorios dentro de cada usuario le pertenezcan a dicho usuario, deberías hacer:

```sh
cd /home/
chown -R user1 user1-dir
chown -R user2 user2-dir
```

O en caso también necesites aplicar el grupo, si hay un grupo por cada usuario con el mismo nombre:

```sh
chown -R user1.user1 user1-dir
chown -R user2.user2 user2-dir
```